# Using $cookies and $stateChangeStart to check for sessionID exeeding maximum callstack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I'm not really sure why this is happening. I'm trying to listen to each state change in my Angular application and push the user back to login if they're not Auth. I'm storing their encrypted sessionID in a cookie, checking if that cookie is undefined and the redirecting the user as such.. or at least that's what I'm trying to do. I will be using the toState and toParams arguments down the road for user role's etc. so you can ignore those as part of this task for now.

Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

```
.run(($rootScope, $state, $cookies) => {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (evt, toState, toParams) => {
            if(!$cookies.get('SessionID')){
                evt.preventDefault();
                $state.go('login');
            }
        })
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing this on every state change, you've created an infinite loop. you might pretty this up a bit, but this should get you there:

```
.run(($rootScope, $state, $cookies) => {
      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (evt, toState, toParams) => {
            if(!$cookies.get('SessionID'))
               {
                if (toState.name !== "login") {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $state.go('login');
               }
            }
        })
  })
```

The above will get you started, but as you move forward you'll find that there are other states that you want to allow access to without cookies or authentication as well. The best way to handle this is probably with a custom property that you define on each state. So when you define your states you would do something like:

```
.state('home', {url: '/home', templateUrl: 'views/home.html', authRequired: false}) 
.state('someSecureUrl', {url: '/someSecure.url', templateUrl: 'views/someSecureUrl.html', authRequired: true})
```

then modify the code above to be something like:

```
.run(($rootScope, $state, $cookies) => {
          $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', (evt, toState, toParams) => {
                if(!$cookies.get('SessionID')  && toState.authRequired)
                   {
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            })
      })
```

You can also look at doing this using a resolve function on your states.

Comment: Awesome! This actually worked. Now how would I implement this along side the ability to hit the 'signin' state as well? I'm researching $state atm and I can't seem to find anything that would let this apply to both states.. unless I nested the states in parent state and gave permissions to parent state of Login/Signup? Something like $state.go('auth') (which would route to login for it will be mostly used).. would that work? @MikeFeltman